# How to make this app screen scroll?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uiscrollview

I've a screen in an app I'm coding structured like this:

```
View
    ScrollView
        View
            label 1
            label 2
            label 3
        View
            UIImageView
        WebView
```

When loaded it adds some html string into the Web View and as the whole content (labels,image,html content) is longer than the screen height, I would like to allow the screen to scroll down/up when user is reading content. This is why I added the SrollView but nothing scroll!

I also did is `scroll_view.contentSize = [self.view bounds].size;` but it didn't work

Any idea on how to do this ?

Thx in advance for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 2):

By default *UIScrollView* is set a *`contentSize`* equal to its *`frame`* size. If you want it to be scrollable, you have to explicitly set the *contentSize*.

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_width, _height);
```

Mostly you won't be knowing the actual contents size while you create the scroll view. You can assign the *contentSize* after adding the *UIWebview*(as web view is the last view in your scroll view). You can do it like this,

```
// Add other views to scrollView
// Create and configure webView
[scrollView addSubview:webView];

float _width = scrollView.contentSize.width; // No change in width
float _height = CGRectGetMaxY(webView); // Returns (webView.frame.origin.y + webView.frame.size.height)
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_width, _height);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code u observe Here "Height" declare Dynamically as your Requirement

```
EXample :
if([Myarray  length]>25)
{

myString = [myString stringByAppendingFormat:@"<tr><th align=\"left\">%@</tr>",str_owes ];
height += 50;
}

  webview.frame=CGRectMake(25, 153, 420, height);
 [webview loadHTMLString:myString baseURL:nil]; 

scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(0, webview.frame.origin.y+webview.frame.size.height+50);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `UIScrollView`'s `contentSize` to be the size of the two views + the UIWebView combined.

You will also need to make sure that the `UIWebView` if of the right size and then turn scrolling off, as you may get scrolling issues otherwise (one scroll view inside another).

More info: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

Comment: What I did is scroll_view.contentSize = [self.view bounds].size; but it didn't work

Comment: `CGSizeMake(scrollView.contentSize.width, CGRectGetMaxY(UIWebView));` The UIWebView should be the instance, not the class.